# Освобожденеи памяти после перезагрузки в DataFrame

Tags: python, память, pandas, dataframe

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. При перезагрузке данных в DataFrame (использовании того же идентификатора) занимаемая память удваивается.

Например:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('D:\\temp\\PL_1.dsv', sep=';')
df1 = pd.read_csv('D:\\temp\\PL_1.dsv', sep=';')
```

Пример искусственный, но наглядно показывает проблему. Пусть после первой загрузки в `df1` выбранная у системы память будет условных 300Мб. После второй - 600Мб (по данным диспетчера задач Windows).
В моем представлении объект, с которым связан идентификатор `df1`, должен удалиться с соответствующим освобождением памяти. Но этого не происходит.
Где-то читал, что python при освобождении памяти не отдает ее обратно системе. Но как быть, если в итоге python выдает ошибку переполнения MemorryError.

Непонятна причина. Kак правильно обрабатывать подобные ситуации?

И даже такой код как

```
pd.read_csv('D:\\temp\\PL_1.dsv', sep=';').head(1000)
```

грузит весь файл в память и не освобождает ее. Т.е. в переменной датафрейм из 1000 строк, а памяти занято 500Мб. Как с этим работать - непонятно

Comment: Кажется, этот же вопрос на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557074

Comment: Пробовали явно удалять переменную: `del df1`?

Comment: Пробовал. Реально освобождает память, но только последней загрузки. Т.е. в этом случае выполнить, что-то типа `df1 = df1.drop(labels=0, axis=0)` все равно не понятно как.

Comment: Фактически попутно возник следующий вопрос. Почему команда `drop` потребляет такое большое количество памяти, сравнимое или даже больше, чем сам DataFrame, несмотря на то, что используется `inplace=True`.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите избавиться от некоторых прочитанных из CSV столбцов, то гораздо быстрее и эффективнее будет не читать ненужные столбцы вовсе:

можно использовать либо имена столбцов:

```
cols = ['colA', 'colC', 'colE', 'colJ']
```

либо их порядковые номера:

```
cols = [0, 2, 5, 9]

df1 = pd.read_csv('D:\\temp\\PL_1.dsv', sep=';', usecols=cols)
```

Comment: Здесь даже больше вопрос о распределении памяти при "освобождении переменной". Появился еще один попутный вопрос. При попытке удалить хотя бы одну запись, например так: `df1.drop(labels=0, axis=0, inplace=True)` происходит многократное увеличение памяти (наблюдаю через диспетчер задач) и при достижении того же около 1Гб выбрасывает ошибку MemorryError.